# mongod isn't start the server

Tags: database, mongodb

[screenshot of hyper terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wiq3u.png)

Error meassage:

```
$ mongod
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:46.725+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:46.729+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.185+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.186+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.187+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.188+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.188+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.188+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.190+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":6768,"port":27017,"dbPath":"C:/data/db/","architecture":"64-bit","host":"DESKTOP-CLTB79I"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.190+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23398,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Target operating system minimum version","attr":{"targetMinOS":"Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2"}}       
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.190+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.9","gitVersion":"6f7dae919422dcd7f4892c10ff20cdc721ad00e6","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"windows","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.190+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Microsoft Windows 10","version":"10.0 (build 19044)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.190+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.193+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"C:/data/db/","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.193+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=3467M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.218+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1658693027:217875][6768:140736190502224], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 4 through 5"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.277+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1658693027:276900][6768:140736190502224], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 5 through 5"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.368+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1658693027:368318][6768:140736190502224], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_ALL] Main recovery loop: starting at 4/1152 to 5/256"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.484+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1658693027:484501][6768:140736190502224], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 4 through 5"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.572+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1658693027:571323][6768:140736190502224], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 5 through 5"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.658+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1658693027:657854][6768:140736190502224], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_ALL] Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.658+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1658693027:658849][6768:140736190502224], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_ALL] Set global oldest timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.660+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1658693027:659850][6768:140736190502224], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 1, snapshot max: 1 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 73"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.666+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":473}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.666+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.667+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4366408, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"No table logging settings modifications are required for existing WiredTiger tables","attr":{"loggingEnabled":true}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.670+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.672+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.672+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22140,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"This server is bound to localhost. Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.675+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20573,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Wrong mongod version","attr":{"error":"UPGRADE PROBLEM: Found an invalid featureCompatibilityVersion document (ERROR: Location4926900: Invalid featureCompatibilityVersion document in admin.system.version: { _id: \"featureCompatibilityVersion\", version: \"6.0\" }. See https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/4.4-compatibility/#feature-compatibility. :: caused by :: Invalid value for featureCompatibilityVersiondocument in admin.system.version, found 6.0, expected '4.4' or '4.9' or '5.0. See https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/4.4-compatibility/#feature-compatibility.). If the current featureCompatibilityVersion is below 4.4, see the documentation on upgrading at https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/4.4/#upgrade-procedures."}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.676+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.676+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.677+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.677+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.677+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.677+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.677+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.678+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784908, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the PeriodicThreadToAbortExpiredTransactions"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.678+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784909, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicationCoordinator"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.678+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784910, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ShardingInitializationMongoD"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.678+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784911, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Enqueuing the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.679+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784912, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Killing all operations for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.679+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4695300, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Interrupted all currently running operations","attr":{"opsKilled":3}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.679+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"TENANT_M", "id":5093807, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down all TenantMigrationAccessBlockers on global shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.679+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784913, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down all open transactions"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.680+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784914, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.680+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":4784915, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the IndexBuildsCoordinator"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.681+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784916, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Reacquiring the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.681+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784917, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Attempting to mark clean shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.682+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.682+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.683+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.683+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.684+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.684+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.685+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.685+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.685+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784930, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the storage engine"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.686+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22320,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down journal flusher thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.687+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22321,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Finished shutting down journal flusher thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.687+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22322,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down checkpoint thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.688+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22323,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Finished shutting down checkpoint thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.688+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20282,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Deregistering all the collections"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.689+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22261,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor shutting down"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.689+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22317,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.689+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22318,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down session sweeper thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.689+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22319,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Finished shutting down session sweeper thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.690+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Closing WiredTiger","attr":{"closeConfig":"leak_memory=true,"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.691+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1658693027:690742][6768:140736190502224], close_ckpt: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 2, snapshot max: 2 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 73"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.700+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger closed","attr":{"durationMillis":10}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.700+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22281,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"shutdown: removing fs lock..."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.701+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.701+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.702+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-25T01:33:47.704+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":62}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is this:

> {"error":"UPGRADE PROBLEM: Found an invalid featureCompatibilityVersion document (ERROR: Location4926900: Invalid featureCompatibilityVersion document in admin.system.version: { _id: "featureCompatibilityVersion", version: "6.0" }. See https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/4.4-compatibility/#feature-compatibility. :: caused by :: Invalid value for featureCompatibilityVersiondocument in admin.system.version, found 6.0, expected '4.4' or '4.9' or '5.0. See https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/4.4-compatibility/#feature-compatibility.). If the current featureCompatibilityVersion is below 4.4, see the documentation on upgrading at [https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/4.4/#upgrade-procedures."}}](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/4.4/#upgrade-procedures.%22%7D%7D)

I guess you upgraded your MongoDB but you did not follow the instruction as given in the error message.

Perhaps you tried to upgrade from version 4.4 directly to version 6.0. This is not possible, see [Upgrade Version Path](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/upcoming/release-notes/6.0-upgrade-standalone/)

> To upgrade an existing MongoDB deployment to 6.0, you must be running a 5.0-series release.
>
> To upgrade from a version earlier than the 5.0-series, you must successively upgrade major releases until you have upgraded to 5.0-series. For example, if you are running a 4.4-series, you must upgrade first to 5.0 before you can upgrade to 6.0.