# Can't run MongoDB 6.x mongodb-community on macOS Monterey 12.6

Tags: mongodb, macos, homebrew

Have always installed MongoDB mongodb-community on 'brew' & run on macOS 12.6:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/5.0.7/bin/install_compass
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/5.0.7/bin/mongo
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/5.0.7/bin/mongod
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/5.0.7/bin/mongos
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/5.0.7/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/5.0.7/MPL-2
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/5.0.7/THIRD-PARTY-NOTICES
```

Runs OK:

```
./mongod  --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

Run './mongo' OK with:

```
MongoDB shell version v5.0.7
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("09dd630d-5a50-4498-9791-fd8bfe03ed2f") }
MongoDB server version: 5.0.7
================
Warning: the "mongo" shell has been superseded by "mongosh",
which delivers improved usability and compatibility.The "mongo" shell has been deprecated and will be removed in
an upcoming release.
For installation instructions, see
https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/install/
================
---
The server generated these startup warnings when booting: 
        2022-09-15T13:33:04.913+01:00: Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted
        2022-09-15T13:33:04.931+01:00: Soft rlimits for open file descriptors too low
        2022-09-15T13:33:04.931+01:00:         currentValue: 256
        2022-09-15T13:33:04.931+01:00:         recommendedMinimum: 64000
---
---
        Enable MongoDB's free cloud-based monitoring service, which will then receive and display
        metrics about your deployment (disk utilization, CPU, operation statistics, etc).

        The monitoring data will be available on a MongoDB website with a unique URL accessible to you
        and anyone you share the URL with. MongoDB may use this information to make product
        improvements and to suggest MongoDB products and deployment options to you.

        To enable free monitoring, run the following command: db.enableFreeMonitoring()
        To permanently disable this reminder, run the following command: db.disableFreeMonitoring()
---
>
```

All fine. If I install 'mongodb/brew/mongodb-community 6.0.1' won't run at all.

```
brew list mongodb-community
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.1/bin/install_compass
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.1/bin/mongod
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.1/bin/mongos
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.1/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.1/MPL-2
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.1/THIRD-PARTY-NOTICES
```

Run:

```
MacBook-Pro-2:bin NOTiFY$ pwd
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb-community/6.0.1/bin
MacBook-Pro-2:bin NOTiFY$ ./mongod  --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf 
MacBook-Pro-2:bin NOTiF
```

mongod.conf:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Nothing happens!

**+ 2**

brew Upgrading:

```
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package:
mongodb/brew/mongodb-community 6.0.1
==> Downloading https://fastdl.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-macos-x86_64-6.0.1.tgz
Already downloaded: /Users/NOTiFY/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/6c0276d76a317be5ff37eb28eec23556e953dd6c89bb7f09086f6036b5c506b8--mongodb-macos-x86_64-6.0.1.tgz
==> Upgrading mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
  -> 6.0.1 

==> Successfully started `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community)
```

Gives:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:06.610+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:06.612+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:06.612+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:06.614+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:06.614+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:06.614+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:06.614+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:06.614+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":27698,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/usr/local/var/mongodb","architecture":"64-bit","host":"MacBook-Pro-2.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:06.614+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.1","gitVersion":"32f0f9c88dc44a2c8073a5bd47cf779d4bfdee6b","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:06.614+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"21.6.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:06.614+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/usr/local/var/mongodb"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:06.615+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":5693100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Asio socket.set_option failed with std::system_error","attr":{"note":"acceptor TCP fast open","option":{"level":6,"name":261,"data":"00 04 00 00"},"error":{"what":"set_option: Invalid argument","message":"Invalid argument","category":"asio.system","value":22}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:06.616+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/usr/local/var/mongodb","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:06.617+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=32256M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,remove=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=2000),statistics_log=(wait=0),json_output=(error,message),verbose=[recovery_progress:1,checkpoint_progress:1,compact_progress:1,backup:0,checkpoint:0,compact:0,evict:0,history_store:0,recovery:0,rts:0,salvage:0,tiered:0,timestamp:0,transaction:0,verify:0,log:0],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.523+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":906}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.523+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.524+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WT",       "id":4366408, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"No table logging settings modifications are required for existing WiredTiger tables","attr":{"loggingEnabled":true}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.603+01:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.607+01:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20573,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Wrong mongod version","attr":{"error":"UPGRADE PROBLEM: Found an invalid featureCompatibilityVersion document (ERROR: Location4926900: Invalid featureCompatibilityVersion document in admin.system.version: { _id: \"featureCompatibilityVersion\", version: \"4.4\" }. See https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/5.0-compatibility/#feature-compatibility. :: caused by :: Invalid feature compatibility version value, expected '5.0' or '5.3' or '6.0. See https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/5.0-compatibility/#feature-compatibility.). If the current featureCompatibilityVersion is below 5.0, see the documentation on upgrading at https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/5.0/#upgrade-procedures."}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.607+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.607+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4794602, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Attempting to enter quiesce mode"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.607+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":6371601, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FLE Crud thread pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.607+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.607+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.607+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.607+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.607+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.607+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.607+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784908, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the PeriodicThreadToAbortExpiredTransactions"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.607+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784909, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicationCoordinator"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.607+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784910, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ShardingInitializationMongoD"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.607+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784911, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Enqueuing the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.607+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784912, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Killing all operations for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.607+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4695300, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Interrupted all currently running operations","attr":{"opsKilled":3}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.607+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"TENANT_M", "id":5093807, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down all TenantMigrationAccessBlockers on global shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.607+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784913, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down all open transactions"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.607+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784914, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.607+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":4784915, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the IndexBuildsCoordinator"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.607+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.607+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.607+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.608+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.608+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.608+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.608+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.608+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6278511, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the Change Stream Expired Pre-images Remover"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.608+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.608+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784930, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the storage engine"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.608+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22320,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down journal flusher thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.608+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22321,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Finished shutting down journal flusher thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.608+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22322,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down checkpoint thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.608+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22323,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Finished shutting down checkpoint thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.608+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20282,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Deregistering all the collections"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.608+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22317,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.608+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22318,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down session sweeper thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.608+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22319,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Finished shutting down session sweeper thread"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.608+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Closing WiredTiger","attr":{"closeConfig":"leak_memory=true,"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.820+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger closed","attr":{"durationMillis":212}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.820+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22279,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"shutdown: removing fs lock..."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.820+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.820+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-16T14:26:07.820+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":62}}
```

What does this refer to?:

```
(ERROR: Location4926900: Invalid featureCompatibilityVersion document in admin.system.version: { _id: \"featureCompatibilityVersion\", version: \"4.4\" }. See https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/5.0-compatibility/#feature-compatibility. :: caused by :: Invalid feature compatibility version value, expected '5.0' or '5.3' or '6.0. See https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/5.0-compatibility/#feature-compatibility.). If the current featureCompatibilityVersion is below 5.0, see the documentation on upgrading at https://docs.mongodb.com/master/release-notes/5.0/#upgrade-procedures."}}
```

> MacBook-Pro-2:bin NOTiFY$ mongod --version db version v6.0.1 Build
> Info: {
> "version": "6.0.1",
> "gitVersion": "32f0f9c88dc44a2c8073a5bd47cf779d4bfdee6b",
> "modules": [],
> "allocator": "system",
> "environment": {
> "distarch": "x86_64",
> "target_arch": "x86_64"
> } }

Is this the cause?:

[mongod isn't start the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73101650/mongod-isnt-start-the-server)

Comment: Check the logfile `/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log`

Comment: The last code block does not make any sense. `mongosh` is the mongo shell, it is used to connect to a running `mongod / mongos` server.

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit - I was confused with the "MongoDB Shell"  reply. Still can't to run & connect to 'mongod' on macOS Monterey with 6.0.1. I will stay  with 5.0.7 for time. TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with:

```
mongod --repair --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb --storageEngine wiredTiger
```

Comment: Doesn't help unfortunately. I had to delete the old database along with the contents of the /usr/local/var/mongodb/ directory